# Spin and Go Strategy

Tags: online, short-stack

I'd like to discuss strategy for Spin & Go. I'm sure all of you that play online have come across it; 3-handed turbo, 500 starting chips, blinds start at 10/20, go up every 2-3 mins. At the beginning of the game a wheel is spun and designates a prize to the winner (2nd and 3rd take nothing) of at least double the buy-in.

I thought it'd be easiest for me to bullet point things that I do and for you to agree/disagree and say why.

1. Play tighter than 6-max SnGs due to short stack
2. With hands like J10 limp in to see cheap flops
3. Bet sizing smaller, usually around half the pot
4. Less inclined to chase draws
5. Take stabs on the flop with continuation bets but give up quite easily after that if other players looks strong
6. More likely to believe possible bluffs
7. If playing passive players check hand down after flop (and have weak hand)
8. If playing tight players raise pocket pairs
9. If playing aggressive players wait for better hands and then play passively
10. If playing loose players play more aggressively (same with most game-types to be fair)

Alright I think that's it. I've numbered each point so you don't have to answer all of them. Any insights appreciated, and any new points to add welcomed. I only started playing Spin & Gos a week or two ago so my play is quite unrefined, please don't berrate me if you think I'm playing like an idiot. The points are also generalizations and of course vary depending on position, buy-in, prize on the spinner, reads etc. etc.

Comment: This is really broad and 3 handed play is not specific to spin and go.  I don't have the rep  to vote to close.   I suggest you post specific hand, position, and bets.

Comment: Its not just your typical 3 handed play, everyone has short stacks, blinds are increasing fast and winner takes all. Due to this your options are quite limited and there is more likely a 'correct' way of playing.

Comment: I can read the question. There are whole books on poker strategy. Spin and Go is not that unique.  All poker strategies still apply.

Comment: In which case it will be easy for you to see which points I've made are wrong.

Comment: I decline.   SE is not discussion forum for general strategies.  You many get some takers.

Comment: I do think that the Spin&Go format is a very specific format where there are clear right and wrong answers to the above list of 10 questions posted. I'd disagree with all poker strategies applying here.

Comment: @Grinch91 I hope the OP get answers.  How is 3 handed button with 20 bb played different because it is Stop and Go? Do odds or EV change?  What poker strategy does not apply?

Comment: Actually certain concepts don't apply in Spin&Go. It's winner takes all, there is no ICM or bubble factor so your hand ranges aren't effected by them. Stack size compared to the other two players plays no part in a Spin & Go, It is pure ChipEV calculations. Look it's fine if you disagree, let's not turn the comments into a discussion :)

Comment: I would think such strong opinions/beliefs that there is are specific strategies for (or definitely not for) this format would result in answers being posted.